# Google Cloud Storage CNAME URL Redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a public bucket 'wordgamesswf' on Google Cloud storage where objects can be accessed with urls
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/wordgamesswf/linguistics

I need to host the files from my domain so i added a CNAME redirect from wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com to c.storage.googleapis.com

I'm trying to access the object at
http://wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com/linguistics

but im getting the following error

```
    <Error>
     <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
     <Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
    </Error>
```

is there something i missed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your bucket name is `wordgamesswf` and your domain name is `addictingwordgames.com`.

To access objects via http://wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com/linguistics you have to create a bucket named **`"wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com"`** and make CNAME entry as -

**`wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.`**

By doing this, you can use the following URL to access linguistics from **wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com**:

http://wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com/linguistics

Answer (score 2):

This approach worked for me:

1. create a bucket as the same name as your subdomain. like
   sub.domain.ltd
2. Because it is a real subdomain, Google will ask you to verify the
   ownership. Simply follow the requirement and prove you are the owner
   of the domain.
3. create a CNAME for sub.domain.ltd and point it to
   c.storage.googleapis.com.
4. Access your file by going to `sub.domain.ltd/file`. You do not need to go to `sub.domain.ltd/sub.domain.ltd/file`

It should work!
Also, you can use some CDN features on your own subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

For my case on Google Domains, I have done the following setting and it worked :

wordgamesswf CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com

Now I can access GCS Bucket : wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com

via wordgamesswf.addictingwordgames.com/myfile