# Resumable uploads with a custom domain in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm going to be creating resumable upload sessions on the server and passing the url to the client to perform an upload.

I want to initiate a resumable upload but use a custom domain.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#initiate-session

so instead of `https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable&name=my-file.jpg&upload_id=ABg5-UxlRQU75tqTINorGYDgM69mX06CzKO1NRFIMOiuTsu_mVsl3E-3uSVz65l65GYuyBuTPWWICWkinL1FWcbvvOA`

I could use

`https://uploads.mycustomdomain.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable&name=my-file.jpg&upload_id=ABg5-UxlRQU75tqTINorGYDgM69mX06CzKO1NRFIMOiuTsu_mVsl3E-3uSVz65l65GYuyBuTPWWICWkinL1FWcbvvOA`

or
`https://uploads.mycustomdomain.com/o?uploadType=resumable&name=my-file.jpg&upload_id=ABg5-UxlRQU75tqTINorGYDgM69mX06CzKO1NRFIMOiuTsu_mVsl3E-3uSVz65l65GYuyBuTPWWICWkinL1FWcbvvOA`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a similar question at: [Google Cloud Storage CNAME URL Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647700/google-cloud-storage-cname-url-redirect)

It is not an identical question, but a similar one.
Unfortunately for it to work it is required to change CNAME records in your DNS.

Comment: This didn't work with resumable uploads, I got a 404 not found